# State solid hard disk upgrade

Tags: ssd, upgrade

Wha type of connector are mounted on SSD? I'm searching for a new notebook and I'm stuck on this choice.

Could I buy a notebook with a classic HDD and then, upgrade it with a SSD?

Answer (score 2):

Both SSD and HDD hard drives use standard SATA connectors, so yes if you can remove the hard drive from a notebook then you could easily put an SSD back in its place.

Answer (score 1):

> What type of connector are mounted on SSD?

Almost all current drives, both rotating and solid state, use a SATA connector. There are a few exceptions, e.g. with SAS drives, fibrechannel drives or PCI-e based cards which act as a drive, but almost all notebook drives should be SATA.  [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) is backwards compatible, so you can use any SATA drive to replace another SATA drive.

[image: 2.5 and 3.5 inch drive with SATA connector and power connectors]

<sub>Image source: Wikipedia</sub>

That only leaves the form factor. Obviously a 3½ drive is not going to fit in a notebook, so make sure you select a 2½ inch drive. That is the normal size for laptop drives and for almost all SSDs. Next check the thickness of the drive. That is also almost always the same (9.5mm), but making sure that you do not have an ultra-thin drive before trying to replace it with a normal thickness SSD would not hurt.

> Could I buy a notebook with a classic HDD and then, upgrade it with a SSD?

In almost all cases: Yes.